# Load post from Followers in Nodejs and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a schema for post like below, but am having problem fetching post from my followers.  i have also tried using  but all to no avail. please help
I have a schema for post like below, but am having problem fetching post from my followers.  i have also tried using  but all to no avail. please help
I have a schema for post like below, but am having problem fetching post from my followers.  i have also tried using  but all to no avail. please help

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema =new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'users'
    },
    text:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    avatar:{
        type:String
    },
    likes:[
        {
            user:{
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'users'
            }
        }
    ],
    comments:[
        {
            user:{
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'users'
            },
            text:{
                type:String,
                required: true
            },
            name: {
                type: String
            },
            avatar: {
                type: String
            },
            date:{
                type:Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            likes: [
                {
                    user: {
                        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        ref: 'users'
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
    reposter: [
        {
            user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }
    ],

    numberOfRepost: { type: Number, default: 0 },

    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Post = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema);
```

Comment: I have tried this and still not working      Post.find({
        $or: [{ 'user': req.user._id },
        { 'user': {$elemMatch: {user:req.user.followers.user }} }]
    })
        .then(posts => {
            //   console.log("The post: " + post)
            res.json(posts)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nopostfound: 'No posts found' }))

Comment: I could not find any data about "followers" in your schema definition. Kindly add more details in your question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should rethink about mongo-collection design, Here is some tip which it is better to consider.

- Use **Upper Camel** case for declaring mongoose model objects. ( Post, User, ... )
- Always put **_** before any reference variable. ( _user in Post models )
- Separate your collections and avoid **redundant** properties as much as possible.
- Always use **Plural of a name** for collections. ( posts vs post )
- Do not forget to add **created** and **updated** property to each collection. ( this hack helps you for logging and investigating your models )

Now, let's look at our new design:

1. name and avatar are redundant data in the Post model. you can populate them later.
2. Separate Like, Comment, RePoster from Post model.

Here is the refined Post model object.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },

    text:{ type:String, required: true },

    rePostsNum: { type: Number, default: 0 },

    // any other meta data which you need

    creaetd: Date,
    updated: Date
  },
  {  
    collection: 'posts',
    strict: true,
    autoIndex: true
  }
);

PostSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if( this.isNew )
      this.created = new Date();

    this.updated = new Date();

    next();
});

module.exports = Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

You can also put `_comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]` into the Post model, but think about it! If it is possible to store thousands of comments reference key in _comments array, it is not recommended, it's like technical debt.

Other models:

**Comment:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const CommentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    _post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },

    text:{ type:String, required: true },

    likesNum: { type: Number, default: 0 },

    creaetd: Date,
    updated: Date
  },
  {  
    collection: 'posts',
    strict: true,
    autoIndex: true
  }
);

CommentSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if( this.isNew )
      this.created = new Date();

    this.updated = new Date();

    next();
});

module.exports = Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

**LikePost**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const LikePostSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },    
    _post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },

    creaetd: Date,
    updated: Date
  },
  {  
    collection: 'likePosts',
    strict: true,
    autoIndex: true
  }
);

LikePostSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if( this.isNew )
      this.created = new Date();

    this.updated = new Date();

    next();
});

module.exports = LikePost = mongoose.model('LikePost', LikePostSchema);
```

**LikeComment**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

    const LikeCommentSchema = new Schema(
      {
        _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },    
        _comment: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' },

        creaetd: Date,
        updated: Date
      },
      {  
        collection: 'likeComments',
        strict: true,
        autoIndex: true
      }
    );

    LikeCommentSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
        if( this.isNew )
          this.created = new Date();

        this.updated = new Date();

        next();
    });

    module.exports = LikeComment = mongoose.model('LikeComment', LikeCommentSchema);
```

**User**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name:{ type:String, required: true },
    avatar:{ type:String, required: true },

    // any other meta data which you need

    creaetd: Date,
    updated: Date
  },
  {  
    collection: 'users',
    strict: true,
    autoIndex: true
  }
);

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if( this.isNew )
      this.created = new Date();

    this.updated = new Date();

    next();
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**RePost**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const RePostSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },    
    _post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },

    creaetd: Date,
    updated: Date
  },
  {  
    collection: 'rePosts',
    strict: true,
    autoIndex: true
  }
);

RePostSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if( this.isNew )
      this.created = new Date();

    this.updated = new Date();

    next();
});

module.exports = RePost = mongoose.model('RePost', RePostSchema);
```

Welcome back!
Now our new design is fully scalable and guides you to clean and robust code.
Finally, we can query and populate data, Here is two cool sample code:

Load specific user's posts

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var User        = mongoose.model('User');
var Post        = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment     = mongoose.model('Comment');
var LikePost    = mongoose.model('LikePost');
var LikeComment = mongoose.model('LikeComment');
var RePost      = mongoose.model('RePost');


Post
.find({ _user: userId })
.select('_id _user text ...')
.populate({
  path: '_user',
  select: '_id name avatar ...'
})
.exec(function (err, poats) {
```

Load specific post's comments

```
Comment
.find({ _post: postId })
.select('_id _post _user text ...')
.populate({
  path: '_user',
  select: '_id name avatar ...'
})
.exec(function (err, comments) {
```

Comment: I must say, Separating each schema into its own model makes more sense and cool. I initially thought of it, but getting them to relate was a problem but your comment makes it less of an issue which makes more sense. But i need some clarifications like {this.isNew), is it part of the mongoose schema because i dont under stand where it comes from and autoIndex too.  Thanks

Comment: Then as regards my original question. I want to load text from people that i am following..can you help with that??

Comment: The this.isNew is part of mongoose, checkout here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html.

It's better to read mongoose docs for understanding autoIndex and other options.

Comment: Separate following model and develop independent logic for populating data, one function which just returns posts or text of an array of users. break your response into some smaller problems and finally concat them.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String
    },
    phonenumber: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: String
    },
    lastlogin: {
        type: Date, default: Date.now
    },
    passwordUpdated: {
        type: Date, default: Date.now
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: Date
    },
    dateofbirth: {
        type: Date
    },
    dateJoined: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    sentRequest: [{
        username: { type: String, default: '' },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }],
    request: [{
        userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        username: { type: String, default: '' },
        name: { type: String, default: '' },
        phone: { type: String, default: '' },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }],
    friendsList: [{
        friendId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        friendName: { type: String, default: '' },
        friendUsername: { type: String, default: '' },
        friendPhone: { type: String, default: '' },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }],
    followers: [{
        userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }],
    blockedContacts: [
        {
            userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }],

    totalRequest: { type: Number, default: 0 },

    repost: [
        {
            postId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" },
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }
    ],
    accolades: [
        {
            user: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'

            },
            remarks: {
                type: String
            },
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }
    ],

    followers: [{
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
             },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }],
    following: [{
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }],

})

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;

    //check if password is modified, else no need to do anything
    if (!user.isModified('pass')) {
        return next()
    }

    user.pass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
    next()
})
module.exports = User = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

This is the user schema